# how to access the java web project that is hosted on a server through url from anywhere in the world

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I purchased space on Windows Hyper-V server from http://www.databasemart.com/ on which after login I installed eclipse , apache tomcat 7, oracle database and java 1.8.
I wrote a webproject and deployed it on the apache tomcat server installed in the Windows Hyper-V server.
During registeration they had given me a url
airreser.airreservation.com

How do I access the java web project webpages that I have deployed  on the apache tomcat server using the url that was given to me during registration.

I am able to access the project pages on the local host of the server but unable to do so through the url given to me .

Please help me to resolve the issue.

EDIT:
Ping response to the url http://airreser.airreservation.com/
[image]

The ip address of the server where the softwares are installed is 
108.60.213.43

How do I make the requests to the url http://airreser.airreservation.com/

redirect to the localhost of the server present at IP 108.60.213.43.

Comment: Are there any firewall rules that are preventing access?

Comment: Where do i check for the firewall rules and how ?

Comment: I don't know how to check on that particular platform, but it is someplace to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you URL(http://airreser.airreservation.com/) is not responding (I was trying with ping, 80, 8080 ..) it could be a DNS problem. Please check with your DNS provider. 
After that, you have also to check the port 8080 (default one of tomcat), so before checking with your application, the address http://airreser.airreservation.com:8080 should be accessible.